# Why WP rest API in ionic does not work in emulator

Tags: ionic-framework, wordpress-rest-api

I've created a WP rest API that works with ionic app. Does work on my localhost, but when I run the app in a iphone simulator, It does not work. The WP REST API does not display the content anymore.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Have you tried debugging? Are there any errors shown?

Comment: Debug your simulator via Safari browser in case of Iphone. and See your console for Errors.

Answer (score 1):

WordPress by default control the protocols that are allowed to access the framework (http://...., ftp://.....) for security means (https://tommcfarlin.com/what-is-wordpress-kses/).

When running an ionic app on device in debugging or production mode, it specifies the origin of the requests as **ionic://localhost**. Then, you have to tell the WP to accept requests from this origin.

Place this code in your theme's functions.php as it will fix the problem with iOS HTTP requests to the WP REST API:

```
// Adding ionic Protocol Start.

add_filter('kses_allowed_protocols', function ($protocols) {
    $protocols[] = 'ionic';
    return $protocols;
});

// Adding ionic Protocol End.
```

By the way, if you face CORS errors at any time, make sure to place this code also in the functions.php:

```
// Enabling CORS Start.
function handle_preflight()
{

    $origin = get_http_origin();

    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: " . $origin);

    // Specify the allowed HTTP methods.
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Content-Type');

    if ('OPTIONS' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) {
        status_header(200);
        exit();
    }
}

add_action('init', 'handle_preflight');

function add_cors_http_header()
{
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");

}
add_action('init', 'add_cors_http_header');

// Enabling CORS End.
```

Comment: +1 I've tried adding the 
add_filter( 'allowed_http_origins', function ( $origins ) {
 $origins[] = 'capacitor://localhost';
 $origins[] = 'ionic://localhost';
 $origins[] = 'http://localhost';
 $origins[] = 'http://localhost:8080';
 $origins[] = 'http://localhost:8100';
 return $origins;
}

but it wasn't working... Only after adding this 'kses_allowed_protocols' filter my changes were working